# Novice question - Why does this loop not work?

Tags: ruby, loops, user-input

I assumed the following code would merge all different lines of user's input into just one string. The results are different. What is the logic behind this happening?

I was hoping to unite different user inputs into one. Ideally, given the following lines of input:

one
two 
three 
four

I would end up with the string "one\ntwo\nthree\nfour"

This is the code I thought would work:

```
input = ""

while gets != nil
    secondinput= gets
    input << secondinput
end
```

After runnig the above code, input ends up equal to "two\nfour", not "one\ntwo\nthree\nfour"

What is the logic behind this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`gets` will read and return input line

`gets` used in `while` condition will read a line, check it against `nil` and continue execution.
So you just ignoring every second(first, third) line of your input.

Instead save input into variable and do you logic with value saved in that variable

```
input = ""

line = gets
while line != nil
  input << line
  line = gets
end
```

As @Cary Swoveland correctly pointed out, `gets` will never return `nil` and you end up with infinite loop.

`gets` returns given value with "new line" included, you can get rid of new line (`gets.chomp`) and make you code simpler(maybe more readable)

```
input = ""

line = gets.chomp
until line.empty?
  input << line
  line = gets.chomp
end
```

Comment: @CarySwoveland, this is blind copy from OP's sample.

Comment: No need for attribution. Best to keep the answer clean. Will delete this comment when I figure you’ve seen it.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `gets` in two places. Once when you check the condition for the `while` and once when you do `secondinput= gets`. So on the line with the `while` you're basically reading lines `one` and `three` and throwing the value away.

The smallest change I can make to make your code work is

```
input = ""

secondinput = gets
while secondinput != nil 
    input << secondinput
    secondinput = gets
end
```

That way you're only calling `gets` once per iteration of the loop.